# How can I print a list that doesn't have the default [] and is changed to capital letters?

Tags: python

I have a list in python e.g.

`letters = ["a", "b", "e"]`

And I can print it without the default []:

`print(', '.join(letters))`

`a, b, e`

But how can I print out `A, B, E` so that the strings in the list are all uppercase?

I tried doing `print(', '.join(letters).upper)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply `.upper()` to each string in your list:

```py
alist = ["a", "b", "e"]
print(', '.join([c.upper() for c in alist]))
```

Output as requested.

*Update*

Alternatively, since `.join()` produces a string, then `.upper()` will work on that:

`print(', '.join(alist).upper())`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct, but `upper` is a method and so it needs () added to call it.

Your code should look like

`print(', '.join(list).upper())`

Answer (score 0):

You code does work (with a slight modification), you only need to add `()` after `upper`:

`print(', '.join(list).upper())`

Note: I think another variable name would be better than `list` since it is the builtin list class.